# Insert data from one database to another in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

for a school project i have to insert data from a filled database into an empty database using a php script with sql, both databases are on the same server and both have the exact same structure, difference is that one is filled and the other is not.

i made a start:

```
// get data from filled database
$select = $filledDb->prepare("SELECT * FROM artiekelen_inhoud, artikelen, gebruikers, rollen");
$select->execute();

// insert data into empty database
$insert = $emptyDb->prepare("INSERT INTO ");
```

connection to db is already set up and that works fine.

i'm not entirely sure how i should do this, should i insert all the rows manually or is there someway to insert all data with one query or something?

thank you for reading!

Comment: you can export/import the database if db structure and tables are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO destination_database.destination_table
SELECT * 
FROM source_database.source_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) for this. In short you just do:

```
INSERT INTO dba.blanktable
 SELECT * FROM dbb.yourothertable;
```

This assume that both tables exist, target table is empty and both have somewhat similar column types.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the `SELECT and the INSERT` within one query by running:

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1 SELECT * FROM db2.table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO NEWDB.TABLE_NAME SELECT * FROM SOURSE_DATABASE.TABLE_NAME;
```